# Not able to return list

Tags: python, function, return

Is there any difference between these two ways of returning lists?

Initially the list is empty.

```
my_list = []
```

method 1:

```
my_list.append(1)
return my_list
```

method 2

```
return my_list.append(1)
```

Actually, the second method is returning an empty list for me. Please clarify why it is happening like this

Comment: Because `.append()` doesn't returns anything.

Comment: `.append()` doesn't return the list, it will only add a new element to the list like `a[len(a):] = [x]` does. Like [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_append.htm) Python tutorials says: *This method does not return any value but updates existing list.*

Comment: "Actually, the second method is returning an empty list for me." No; it is returning the special value `None`, which is not a list.

Answer (score 2):

When you type the following:

```
return my_list
```

You are returning a list object. When you type the following:

```
return my_list.append(something)
```

You are returning the result of that method call. In the case of .append() that method is void, so you are effectively returning nothing. If the method .append() appended the argument you pass to it **and then returned the modified list itself** then you could do it, but that isn't the case.